# Special theory of relativety

Tags: special-relativity

Why any body cannot have its speed greater than the speed of the speed of light in any medium according to the theory of relatively by Einstein?

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

Just assume a spacecraft is moving away from a planet with velocity greater than c. If driver of craft switch on a torch in direction of Craft's  than light coming out the torch will be seen like light goes in the direction of Craft's velocity in Craft's frame. While in planet's frame light will be seen like it goes to the back of spacecraft. The principle of relativity would be violated. Hence Craft's velocity can't reach greater than c. As given in 'Concepts of modern physics by Arthur Beiser' page 8, can be easily downloaded from web.